# Public symbols not exported as visible symbols in Rust crate built as a static library ELF file

Tags: rust, visibility, elf

I'm building a Rust crate as a static library, and wish to export all publicly-visible symbols at the Rust level such that they are also visible in the ELF file, namely with GLOBAL binding and DEFAULT visibility.

However, some symbols show up as GLOBAL binding with **HIDDEN** visibility, which means that when I load this static library, those symbols aren't visible. In C with GCC extensions, you can use `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to accomplish this on a per-symbol basis, which is tedious but I guess would be okay for my use case. How can I do this in Rust?

Here's a code example to further illustrate my issue.

In `lib.rs` of my crate:

```
extern crate compiler_builtins;
// readelf shows these symbols as GLOBAL, HIDDEN, which is not what I want.
pub use compiler_builtins::float::conv::__floatundidf;
pub use compiler_builtins::int::mul::__muloti4;
pub use compiler_builtins::int::udiv::{__udivti3, __umodti3};

pub fn my_func() -> {...}   // readelf shows this as GLOBAL, DEFAULT, which is good!
```

I'm building a static library, so all of the symbols do appear in the ELF file (I'm not using `--gc-sections` because I want them to appear), it's just that the imported ones don't have the proper DEFAULT visibility. Hopefully there's a way I can force them to have DEFAULT visibility at the source level (maybe an annotation or attribute), but I haven't been able to find one, so I'd accept a linker argument or script addition as well.